# Staying logged in when updating code on flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, authentication, reload, hot-reload

I am developing an app on flutter which has a login page.

When I run the app on an emulator and then when I do updates which activate the hot reload (I'm using VS Code), the app refresh without asking me to login again.

But when I run the app on the web, each time I have to reload the app I need to enter my login informations.

Do you know how to work around that ?

Thanks.

Comment: I also have this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a simple answer to this problem but what I did is that I added some logic in my **main** and my **LoginScreen** and used **SharedPreferences**.

In my **LoginScreen**, after the authentification is successfully validated I set my login informations in **SharedPreferences**, and the "isLoggedIn" boolean to true :

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        prefs.setString('email', encrypt(data.name, key));
        prefs.setString('password', encrypt(data.password, key));
        prefs.setBool("isLoggedIn", true);
```

In the **initState** function of my **main** I check if I'm supposed to already be logged in and I call my authentification function using the login informations I already stored in SharedPreferences :

```
if (prefs.getBool("isLoggedIn") == true) {
      await authentification(decrypt(prefs.getString('email').toString(), key), decrypt(prefs.getString('password').toString(), key));
loggedIn = prefs.getBool("isLoggedIn");
```

I define a **displayFunction** to choose which screen my app gonna return depending on my loggedIn boolean :

```
Widget displayPage() {
    Widget widget = CircularProgressIndicator();
    if (isDataLoaded == true) {
      if (loggedIn == true) {
        widget = HomePage();
      } else {
        widget = LoginScreen();
      }
    }
    return widget;
  }

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.apply(
              bodyColor: LightColors.kDarkBlue,
              displayColor: LightColors.kDarkBlue,
              fontFamily: 'Poppins'
            ),
      ),
      home: displayPage(),
    ); 
  }
```

In my logout function I set "isLoggedIn" to false :

```
prefs.setBool("isLoggedIn", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything but the only helpful method for me was Shared Preferences.
On Login set Bool isLoggedIn = true and check that on splash to keep login.

```
`SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.setBool('isLoggedIn', true);`
```

splash code

```
    bool loggedIn = false;

  checkLoggedIn() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      loggedIn = prefs.getBool('isLoggedIn') ?? false;
    });
  }

navigate() async {
    _animationController.forward(from: 0.0).whenComplete(() {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => !loggedIn ? SignIn() : MainScreen()));
    });
  }
```

hope so this will help.